# Error: Returned error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value at Object.ErrorResponse

Tags: solidity

[image]
I am using web3 version 1.3.3 and tried to call the contract method using send() but it is showing an error above( Error: Returned error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value at Object.ErrorResponse )

```
const ERC20ListInst = await this.contract;
const res = await ERC20ListInst.methods.tokenToWei(addr, this.web3.utils.toHex(amount)).send({
   from: this.web3.eth.defaultAccount,
   gas: 100000
});
```

I have enough eth on the account and can't sure why this is happening. Is there anyone has faced this one before?

Comment: Are you testing against a public testnet or a private testnet? How do you connect to it? Is the node fully synchronized?

Comment: I am testing it with Goerli testnet. Thanks

Comment: Are you using infura or your own node? Are you sure `this.web3.eth.defaultAccount` has enough balance to pay for the transaction?

Comment: I am using infura and also account has enough balance I think (0.6eth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was issue on truffle wallet provider url.
I was going to use Goerli and there was enough fund but I wrote with mainnet url.
So it was checking mainnet account and showing me insufficient balance.
After I indicate wallet provider to goerli then it worked.
Thanks.